# How to fetch last one year's data in SQl with out date, timestamp columns?

Tags: sql

I have  a table containing years of data but no date or timestamp columns. Now I have to fetch last one year's data. How can achieve that when the table does not have any timestamp or date columns ?

Comment: But you said it has the year. If you want *last year's* data, then (based on today's date) that would be where the year column has the value `2020`.

Comment: In theory, @Larnu. Not in this particular case as "... table does not have any timestamp or date columns". Swetha, if you don't have such columns, you're out of luck.

Comment: I read it as the OP has a year column, perhaps not, @Littlefoot (but if so, their wording is a little odd). But if that is the case you are right; RDBMS only store what you tell them to about the row and if you don't "tell" it to store things like the row's created date, modified date, etc, then it has *no* idea what they are.

Comment: You just can't.

Answer (score -1):

Note: This question was originally asked with the Oracle tag - this answer was based on that and the tag was subsequently removed from the question.

> How can achieve that when the table does not have any timestamp or date columns?

In general, you cannot; if you do not have any data inside the table to tell you a date associated with the row then there is not any meta-data that will tell you.

---

In Oracle, if you have enabled flashback (with a large enough history) on the table then you could compare the state of the table now to the state of the table a year ago using something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table_name AS OF ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12);
```

Comment: @MTO Is flash back feature available in sql server ? I read somewhere that this feature is available in oracle and there is no equivalent feature in sql server. Please correct me if I am wrong